# Woocommerce get the product title on image hover

Tags: php, jquery, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been trying to edit a main theme file in order to show the product title on image hover. We have a similar function, but actually shows the categories of the product, not his title.

Here's the code I've been trying to edit in order to get the products title:

```
<div class="bg-overlay"></div>

           <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="link-overlay"></a>

           <div class="text-on-hover-wrap">

            <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title' ); ?>

            <?php



            if ( $woocommerce && version_compare( $woocommerce->version, '3.0', '>=' ) ) {

                echo '<div class="categories">' . wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id() ) . '</div>';

            } else {

                echo '<div class="categories">' . $product->get_categories() . '</div>';

            }



            ?>

        </div>
```

I just want to get the product title instead of the categories terms.

Print of the style: https://prnt.sc/WZIgbMQNAb_5

Any help would be grateful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace this code section.

```
    if ( $woocommerce && version_compare( $woocommerce->version, '3.0', '>=' ) ) {

        echo '<div class="categories">' . wc_get_product_category_list( $product->get_id() ) . '</div>';

    } else {

        echo '<div class="categories">' . $product->get_categories() . '</div>';

    }
```

to this.

```
echo '<div class="categories">' . $product->get_title() . '</div>';
```